# Why does my C program fail randomly at write?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I have written a proxy that accepts connections from host1 and forwards the connection toward server2.

I accept a connection and then I start two threads to handle the connections... One thread to receive from host 1 and send to server2, and another thread to receive form server2 and send to host1.

My program compiles with no errors, and when I run it and connect host 1 my program fails at the function WRITE after some short time with no error.

The connection is OK, it just fails after short period of time, before write.

Also you can find the written function that I am using.
The code is failing at the CONTROLLER thread, when the controller is writing to the socket.

Why does the program fail with no error message at all?

```
/*
 *     File Server0.c
 *    ECHO TCP SERVER with the following features:
 *      - Gets port from keyboard
 *      - SEQUENTIAL: serves one client at a time
 */
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <inttypes.h>
#include    "mysocket.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h> /* POSIX threads */

#define RBUFLEN        16384

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */
int mygetline(char * line, size_t maxline, char *prompt);
int writen(SOCKET, char *, size_t);
void *mininet(void *);
void *controller(void *);

SOCKET             s,s1[100],d[100];
int y=0,z=0;

int main()
{
    uint16_t         lport_n, lport_h;
    int             result;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    struct sockaddr_in     saddr, caddr;
    //fd_set readfds;
    SOCKET             conn_request_skt;
    int             bklog = 2,t=0;
    pthread_t tid1[100];
    pthread_t tid[100];

    /* Initialize socket API if needed */
    SockStartup();

    /* input server port number */
    lport_h=8888;
    lport_n = htons(lport_h);

    /* create the MININET socket */
    printf("Creating first socketn");
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        err_fatal("socket() failed");

    printf("done, socket number %un",s);

    /* bind the MININET socket to any local IP address */
    saddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port        = lport_n;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    showAddr("Binding to address first socket", &saddr);
    result = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(saddr));

    if (result == -1)
        err_fatal("bind() failed");

    printf("done.n");

    /* listen on MININET socket */
    printf ("Listening at socket %d with backlog = %d n",s,bklog);
    result = listen(s, bklog);

    if (result == -1)
        err_fatal("listen() failed");

    printf("done.n");
    conn_request_skt=s;

    /* accept next connection from mininet */
    for(;;)
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        z++;
        y++;
        t++;
        d[t] = accept(conn_request_skt, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr, &addrlen);

        if (d[t] == INVALID_SOCKET)
            err_fatal("accept() failed");

        showAddr("Accepted connection from", &caddr);
        printf("new accepted connection socket: %un",d[t]);

        /* serve the client on socket s */
        pthread_create(&tid[t], NULL, mininet, &t);
        pthread_create(&tid1[t], NULL, controller, &t);
        sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void *mininet (void *arg)
{
    char            buf[RBUFLEN];        /* reception buffer */
    int             n,t,k;
    t=y;
    k=z;

    printf("MININET: m is: %d, c is: %d n ", t,k);

    /* main server loop */
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("MININET receiving on socket: %un",d[t]);
        n=recv(d[t], buf, RBUFLEN-1, 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("MININET Read errorn");
            closesocket(d[t]);
            printf("MININET Socket %d closedn", d[t]);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (n==0)
        {
            printf("Connection closed by MININET on socket %dn",d[t]);
            closesocket(d[t]);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Received line from MININET socket %03d :n", d[t]);
            buf[n]=0;
            printf("[%s]n",buf);
            printf("MINET WRITING TO: %un",s1[k]);
            if(writen(s1[k], buf, n) != n)
            printf("Write error while replying TO CONTROLERn");
            else
            printf("Reply sent towards CONTROLERn");
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *controller (void *arg)
{
    char             buf[RBUFLEN];        /* reception buffer */
    uint16_t         lport_n1, lport_h1;    /* port where the server listens (net/host byte ord resp.) */
    int             result, n,t,k;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr1;        /* server and client address structures */
    t=y;
    k=z;

    printf("CONTROLLER: m is: %d, c is: %d n ", t,k);

    /* Initialize socket API if needed */
    SockStartup();
    lport_h1=6633;
    lport_n1 = htons(lport_h1);
    printf("Creating CONTROLLER socketn");
    s1[k] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (s1[k] == INVALID_SOCKET)
        err_fatal("socket() failed");

    printf("done, socket number %un",s1[k]);

    /* bind the socket to any local IP address */
    saddr1.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    saddr1.sin_port        = lport_n1;
    saddr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /* connect */
    showAddr("Connecting to target CONTROLER address", &saddr1);
    result = connect(s1[k], (struct sockaddr *) &saddr1, sizeof(saddr1));

    if (result == -1)
        err_fatal("connect() failed");

    printf("done.n");

    /* main server loop */
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("CONTROLER receiving on socket: %un",s1[k]);
        n=recv(s1[k], buf, RBUFLEN-1, 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("CONTROLER Read errorn");
            closesocket(s1[k]);
            printf("Socket %d closedn", s1[k]);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (n==0)
        {
            printf("Connection closed by CONTROLER on socket %dn",s1[k]);
            closesocket(s1[k]);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Received line from CONTROLER socket %03d :n", s1[k]);
            buf[n]=0;
            printf("[%s]n",buf);
            printf("CONTROLER writing on socket: %un",d[t]);
            if(writen(d[t], buf, n) != n)
                printf("Write error while replying TO MININETn");
            else
                printf("Reply sent towards MININETn");
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Gets a line of text from standard input after having printed a prompt string Substitutes end of line with ''
   Empties standard input buffer but stores at most maxline-1 characters in the passed buffer
*/
int mygetline(char *line, size_t maxline, char *prompt)
{
    char    ch;
    size_t  i;
    printf("%s", prompt);
    for (i=0; i< maxline-1 && (ch = getchar()) != 'n' && ch != EOF; i++)
    *line++ = ch;
    *line = '';
    while (ch != 'n' && ch != EOF)
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF)
        return(EOF);
    else
        return(1);
}

/* Writes nbytes from buffer ptr to stream socket s */
int writen(SOCKET s, char *ptr, size_t nbytes)
{
    size_t nleft;
    ssize_t nwritten;
    for (nleft=nbytes; nleft > 0; )
    {
        nwritten = send(s, ptr, nleft, 0);
        if (nwritten <=0)
            return (nwritten);
        else
        {
            nleft -= nwritten;
            ptr += nwritten;
        }
    }
    return (nbytes - nleft);
}
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get much help posting this much code, particularly when it is so poorly formatted.

Comment: any way , i have a question for you ... this code is working on one VM perfectly, and the same code is not working on another VM... is it possible that the linux OS has something to do with the failure of my code ?

Comment: Passing the address of t as the void* argument for the thread create looks highly dubious, even with the sleep(1) band-aid.  When you pass in that parameter, whatever it points to should not be modified by the calling thread.

Comment: The whole concept of those [100] arrays is just messy and smells of gowrongness.

Comment: " this code is working on one VM perfectly, and the same code is not working on another VM.". It is almost always wrong to say any code is "working perfectly". If it is failing in some environment then the chances are very high that there is a bug in your code that triggers under some cases (e.g. timing related) and not others.

Comment: You don't need to sleep between accepts. I think you need to read a networking tutorial.